# Extract all emails from a text document

Tags: linux, grep, bash-scripting

I have a document that contains text and HTML tags, and there is are a lot of tags like `<label>abc@gmail.com</label>` How do I extract all the emails from this document using Linux commands.

I tried using `grep -e "[a-zA-Z0-9._]\+@[a-zA-Z]\+.[a-zA-Z]\+"` but it didn't work 
The following is an example of such a document:

```
   <tbody><tr class="d_gh d2l-table-row-first" header=""><th class="d_gs d2l-table-cell-first" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><input 
class="d2l-checkbox float_l" type="checkbox" title="Select all rows" onclick="UI.GC('z_k').g_sa(this.checked)" 
name="z_k_cb_sa"></th><th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gw d_gl"><d2l-table-col-sort-button data-d2l-table-sort-field="LastName" 
data-d2l-table-next-sort-dir="asc" title="Sort by Last Name" nosort="">Last 
Name</d2l-table-col-sort-button>,&nbsp;<d2l-table-col-sort-button data-d2l-table-sort-field="FirstName" 
data-d2l-table-next-sort-dir="asc" title="Sort by First Name" nosort="">First Name</d2l-table-col-sort-button></th><th 
scope="col" class="d_hch d_gl">Email Address</th><th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gl"><d2l-table-col-sort-button 
data-d2l-table-sort-field="RoleName" data-d2l-table-next-sort-dir="asc" title="Sort by Role" 
desc="">Role</d2l-table-col-sort-button></th><th scope="col" class="d_hch d_gl 
d2l-table-cell-last"><label>Type</label></th></tr><tr><td class="d_gd_sel d2l-table-cell-first" 
style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="d2l-checkbox" type="checkbox" title="Select Nida" name="SystemContactsGrid_cb" 
value="2" onclick="UI.GC('z_k').g_sr('2')"></td><th scope="row" class="d_ich">Ahmed, Nida</th><td 
class="d_gn"><label>abc@gmail.com</label></td><td><label>Student</label></td><td class="d_gn d2l-table-cell-last"><label>Internal
 Email</label></td></tr><tr><td class="d_gd_sel d2l-table-cell-first" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="d2l-checkbox" 
 type="checkbox" title="Select Milen" name="SystemContactsGrid_cb" value="3" onclick="UI.GC('z_k').g_sr('3')"></td><th 
 scope="row" class="d_ich">Andic, Milena</th><td 
 class="d_gn"><label>abc2@gmail.com</label></td><td><label>Student</label></td><td class="d_gn 
 d2l-table-cell-last"><label>Internal Email</label></td></tr><tr><td class="d_gd_sel d2l-table-cell-first" 
 style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="d2l-checkbox" type="checkbox" title="Select Anthony" name="SystemContactsGrid_cb" 
 value="4" onclick="UI.GC('z_k').g_sr('4')"></td><th scope="row" class="d_ich">Macdonald, Anthony</th><td 
 class="d_gn"><label>abc3@gmail.com</label></td><td><label>Student</label></td><td class="d_gn 
 d2l-table-cell-last"><label>Internal Email</label></td></tr><tr><td class="d_gd_sel d2l-table-cell-first" 
 style="white-space:nowrap;"><input class="d2l-checkbox" type="checkbox" title="Select" name="SystemContactsGrid_cb
```

The output of Linux shell script of command should be 

abc@gmail.com
abc1@gmail.com
abc2@gmail.com
which are the email addresses that o

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites:
[Valid & invalid email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples)
[List of TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)
[Regex for email address (RFC 822)](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @Community I have added an example. That should make it clear

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not a good idea to just plain process a parsed html file.

Try to use something like xmllint

`xmllint --xpath "//label/text()" file`

Please note, the input file should be valid html, the one provided in the example is not.

Example:

```
<body>
    <label>mail@mail.co</label>
    <label>example@mail.com</label>
</body>
```

```
xmllint --xpath "//label/text()" file
```

Outputs:

```
mail@mail.co
example@mail.com
```

Please also note, it will output any value between label tags. (it will also output "Student" as well if your example is formatted correctly) But this should get you going.